# Insert Pictures from camera to SQLite in Android

Tags: android, image, sqlite, path, camera

So here is my question... I've been working on a SQLite Data Base that stores some geolocation data and I'd like insert images from the camera. I've read is better insert the image path instead of the image, but I can't find the way to get the image path.

This is what I've got already.

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

    };

    public File getOutputMediaFile() {

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp"
        );
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        return mediaFile;

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file.getAbsolutePath();
```

that simple :)

So in context it might look something like this

```
           try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                saveFileLocation(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
```

where saveFileLocation is a function you make that takes the path string and saves it to your sql db.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So do you think I cand add this in my getOutputMediaFile function?

Comment: Yes you could. However you would first want to make sure that no exceptions were raised in saving the file, otherwise you may save a location to your db that doesn't exist due to some error. Another option would be to do it like you said in the getOutputMediaFile function, and then if an exception is raised, remove it.

Comment: Sorry to bother but I'm very new on this... When I put this on my function I can't get the string out of the function to print it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, in the `getOutputMediaFile` you are returning a file, and this file will still contain the method of `getAbsolutePath()` where you can obtain the path from. Also make sure you have the write/read permissions in your manifest.

Comment: @WIIJDB Is there any way to view the image form that url that I've got ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do `mediaFile.getAbsolutePath()` to get the path that you want to store in the database.